# Can you pass additional state data through to a (possibly custom) JSONDecoder as part of the Decode operation?

Tags: swift, state, decode, codable, decodable

We have a tree-based data model that is based around the `Codable` protocol.   The root of the tree holds its immediate children, as well as a reference to all children in the hierarchy, as seen here...

```
Root
 |
 |-->Children
 |   |
 |   |-->Item 1
 |   |-->Item 2
 |   |   |
 |   |   \-->Children
 |   |       |
 |   |       \-->Item 3
 |   |
 |   \-->Item 4
 |       |
 |       \-->Children
 |           |
 |           \-->Item 5
 |               |
 |               \-->Children
 |                   |
 |                   \-->Item 6
 |
 \-->AllChildren  <<-- Not Serialized!!
      |
      |-->Item 1
      |-->Item 2
      |-->Item 3
      |-->Item 4
      |-->Item 5
      \-->Item 6
```

Now the `AllChildren` part isn't serialized as they are just references to the actual instances from above.

To make the above work, we need to populate `AllChildren` programmatically, as those children are being decoded. However, we aren't sure how to pass the `Root` object into the children's `init(from:Decoder)` calls to handle that as we don't see any way to pass additional state data into the decoding chain. It seems the only information you have available is the `Decoder`, which you don't control.

Our work-around is inside the `init(from:Decoder)` of the `Root`, once it's done decoding/initializing all of its children, it then re-crawls the entire hierarchy, slurping up the children, but I really hate that I have to re-crawl the hierarchy after just doing it during the `init(from:Decoder)` pass.

So is there a way to pass additional state information into the `Decode` process, preferably as something on the `Decoder` handed to the `init(from:Decoder)` calls?

Comment: Of course there is, `init(from:Decoder)` is highly customizable.

Comment: Hi @vadian! Yeah, I referenced that above.  But as I said there, you're only handed the decoder.  I need to pass *additional* state data that is not part of the serialized data.  That's what I'm trying to overcome. In the example above, I'm trying to pass 'Root' to every child as it's being decoded. If there was some 'state' field that you could pass to the originating `decode` method, and which would be passed as part of the `Decoder` that's handed to the init functions, that would solve my problem. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign an arbitrary set of key/value pairs to the decoder's `userInfo` and read them in the `init` methods.

Note that the keys to `userInfo` are `CodingUserInfoKey`, but you can create those from strings using `CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "key")!`.

---

EDIT: After a few years, I wanted to update this with a bit better solution, which is to create a custom `init` that accepts a Decoder and use that to pass along state. (You hint at this in the comments, and it really is as easy as that.)

I haven't tested this carefully, and I'm not quite certain the JSON you're using, but I think this approach should make how to adapt it clear.

```
// This works for either structs or classes
struct Item {
    var value: Int
    var children: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case value, children }

    // This is not the normal Decodable. In fact, Item is not Decodable at all
    // It's just an init that takes extra state
    init(from decoder: Decoder, allChildren: inout [Item]) throws {
        // Decode the normal stuff
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.value = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .value)

        // Decode children by hand
        let childrenContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .children)

        var children: [Item] = []
        while !childrenContainer.isAtEnd {
            // For each child, pass along the `allChildren` array
            children.append(try Item(from: decoder, allChildren: &allChildren))
        }
        self.children = children

        // Append self to the list. This creates a depth first search order.
        // Item in this case is a struct, so this is a copy. If Item were a class
        // then this would be a reference.
        allChildren.append(self)
    }
}

struct Root: Decodable {
    var children: [Item]
    var allChildren: [Item]

    // Basically the same as Item, but creates the `allChildren` first.
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var allChildren: [Item] = []

        let childrenContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        var children: [Item] = []
        while !childrenContainer.isAtEnd {
            children.append(try Item(from: decoder, allChildren: &allChildren))
        }

        self.children = children
        self.allChildren = allChildren
    }
}
```

Comment: BIngo!  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was trying to subclass JsonDecoder and hang the data off of that, then cast it in the init calls, but it wasn't working.  This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Sorry.  Have to pull it back.  userInfo is read-only during the decoding process, so there's no way to update it to hold the newly-decoded `Root` object.   Then again, maybe if I pass another proxy object and put *that* in the userData, that would work! Hmmm... Either way, mind posting an example yourself?

Comment: Just tried storing a class in there with a property that I could set, but ran into the issue where the children are decoded before the parent, which makes sense as the parent can't be complete without them, but that also means I can't pass the parent to the children.  I'm now trying the reverse... using that object to hold a list of the created children, which I can use back in the constructor to Root.  Same thing, but a child-first design.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer bc while it didn't solve my problem, my problem was around my data, not the functionality this presents, which is what the question was technically around, so... Then again, you have a rating of 222k!  Good god!!  It's taken me years to get 20k!  How much are you on this thing?!?! lol

Comment: On a side-note, the trick to this was to store a collection in the UserData which I updated when every child was created, then when it deserialized the root (after all the children were created/stored), I just set that as the AllChildren collection.  Done and done!

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe, could you please post a code example of your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 17 you can now use `DecodableWithConfiguration` instead of `Decodable`. This will allow you to pass an object through to the decodable init like so:

```swift
struct DecodingInfo {
    let rootObject: [String: Any]
}

struct Tokens: DecodableWithConfiguration {
        
    init(from decoder: Decoder, configuration: DecodingInfo) throws {
        let root = configuration.rootObject
        // ...
    }
}

// ...

let tokens = try JSONDecoder().decode(Tokens.self, from: data, configuration: DecodingInfo(rootObject: jsonObject))
```

In my use case I decoded the raw json object to a `[String: Any]` to pass into the decoding process so that i could traverse the dictionary based on values I found in the json that would be references to other parts of the json

```
let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as? [String: [String: Any]]
```